# parse delegate to string query c#.net

Tags: c#, parsing, delegates

I want to implement simple LINQ-to-SQL-like functionality in my .net application.
For example i have the following code:

```
userAccounts.Where(ua=>ua.Name=="User1");
```

and i want delegate in Where method to create a string like this

```
"name = 'User1'".
```

How it can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Edit: you mean create a string not parse a string

Comment: i mean parse delegate to string, represent delegate as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is called [Expression Tree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521.aspx).

See [this blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/working-with-linq-s-expression-trees-visually/) on how to parse and visualize the query's .Expression property